# Mistaken block on asking questions

Tags: support, status-bydesign, questions

The site says we are no longer accepting questions from this account when I try to submit a question in physics section. I don't even have a bad reputation. All I asked was one single question which got me two upvotes. So I don't even know why I'm being targeted or something like that.

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5951/2451 , http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6116/2451 , http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/8851/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The system doesn't block you for one upvoted question. Do you have any questions you asked that you deleted?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are _actually unable_ to post a question, right? It's not just a warning that you are in danger of getting blocked?

Comment: Yes I did not delete any questions

Comment: I'm opening my account after several weeks. I asked a question today got two up votes for it and then a ban! Like wow

Comment: For the record, with a post like this it helps a lot if you quote the _exact_ message you're getting. Sometimes the interpretation of what is going on depends on slight details in the wording of the message.

Answer (score 6):

You have been subjected to one of several automated bans that are active on the network. These bans are temporary, but we can't tell you how long they will last.

We can suggest that you follow and read the links in the message you get when you attempt to post a question.

I can tell you about any deleted question associated with your account if you wish, however that is something that will be in public view. Just comment here asking.

Comment: Okay tell me about them

Comment: Your first two questions (asked June 20th and 22nd of this year) were both substantially downvoted—negative 4 and negative 3 respectively—and eventually deleted by an automated process. These count rather heavily against you. Your more recent question—with it's positive 3 vote count—will help to shorten the length of the automated ban. It may be as little as 24 hours, though the details are confidential even from site moderators.

Comment: Thanks @dmckee but don't you think the site shouldve given me a warning first so that I could improve? I just can't even do anything but wait.